# Executing a Script using a Cronjob Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I have a 3 node K8 v1.21 cluster in AWS and looking for SOLID config to run a script using a cronjob. I have seen many documents on here and Google using cronjob and hostPath to Persistent Volumes/Claims to using ConfigMaps, the list goes one.

I keep getting "Back-off restarting failed container/CrashLoopBackOff" errors.

Any help is much appreciated.

[cronjob.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdRzy.jpg)

The script I am trying to run is basic for testing only

```
#! /bin/<br/>
kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx
```

Still getting the same error.

[kubectl describe pod/xxxx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHTSg.png)

This hostPath in AWS cluster created using eksctl works.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: redis-hostpath
spec:
  containers:
  - image: redis
    name: redis-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /test-mnt
      name: test-vol
  volumes:
  - name: test-vol
    hostPath:
      path: /test-vol
```

**UPDATE**

Tried running your config in GCP on a fresh cluster. Only thing I changed was the /home/script.sh to /home/admin/script.sh

Did you test this on your cluster?

```
Warning  FailedPostStartHook  5m27s  kubelet            Exec lifecycle hook ([/home/mchung/script.sh]) for Container "busybox" in Pod "dumb-job-1635012900-qphqr_default(305c4ed4-08d1-4585-83e0-37a2bc008487)" failed - error: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to exec in container: failed to create exec "0f9f72ccc6279542f18ebe77f497e8c2a8fd52f8dfad118c723a1ba025b05771": cannot exec in a deleted state: unknown, message: ""
  Normal   Killing              5m27s  kubelet            FailedPostStartHook
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, edit your question and add the specs of what you are trying to run. A Pod in CrashLoopBackOff means that it is throwing an error, possibly from the script it is trying to execute. Can you post the yaml definition of your cronjob?

Comment: Like @AndD said, attach the YAML manifest to your question. Also provide the logs of that failing pod by running `kubectl logs <pod_name>`, that'd be helpful too. The more info you provide, the easier it is to debug the issue.

Comment: Ya, just joined and trying to figure out how to paste the manifest in here

Comment: I am not allowed to included embedded images yet, so click on the link

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're running it in a remote multi-node cluster (since you mentioned AWS in your question), `hostPath` is NOT an option there for volume mount. Your best choice would be to use a **ConfigMap** and use it as volume mount.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: redis-script
data:
  script.sh: |
    # write down your script here
```

And then:

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: redis-job
spec:
  schedule: '*/5 * * * *'
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: redis-container
              image: redis
              args:
                - /bin/sh
                - -c
                - /home/user/script.sh
              volumeMounts:
                - name: redis-data
                  mountPath: /home/user/script.sh
                  subPath: script.sh
          volumes:
            - name: redis-data
              configMap:
                name: redis-script
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you face any difficulties.

### Update:

I think you're doing something wrong. `kubectl` isn't something you should run from another container / pod. Because it requires the necessary binary to be existed into that container and an appropriate context set. I'm putting a working manifest below for you to understand the whole concept of running a script as a part of cron job:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: script-config
data:
  script.sh: |-
    name=StackOverflow
    echo "I love $name <3"
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: dumb-job
spec:
  schedule: '*/1 * * * *' # every minute
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: busybox
              image: busybox:stable
              lifecycle:
                postStart:
                  exec:
                    command:
                      - /home/script.sh
              volumeMounts:
                - name: some-volume
                  mountPath: /home/script.sh
          volumes:
            - name: some-volume
              configMap:
                name: script-config
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

What it'll do is it'll print some texts in the STDOUT in every minute. Please note that I have put only the commands that container is capable to execute, and `kubectl` is certainly not one of them which exists in that container out-of-the-box. I hope that is enough to answer your question.

Comment: That was helpful. The configMap I came across was this one which was posted here  https://gist.github.com/Odilhao/0df6a910dd3dbb1c4f67cab97945bfa9

Comment: I will try your config and thanks for the fast response

Comment: You're most welcome! If that helps you solving your problem, kindly upvote it and mark it as answer. Cheers!

Comment: I noticed you didnt include a restartPolicy?

Comment: It's optional. Feel free to add it if need be. :)

Comment: this is what i have for the configmap.yaml   data:
  eicar.sh: kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx

Comment: but still getting the same errors as per my initial post

Comment: Then you need to provide the logs of that pod. See my above comment to the question about how to retrieve logs from a pod.
NOTE: `kubectl` needs to be available in the system in order to execute it as a command. So you're trying to run `kubectl` commands in a [redis](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis) container, which is (by default) not possible. May I know what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @SkyhawkPara92 - It sounds like you are trying to write a script that will create an nginx deployment in your cronJob. To make this possible you will need kubectl in your redis image, a kubeconfig, and connectivity from redis pod to the kubernetes controller.

Comment: @alvite and msrumon, the script can be anything, but yes that is what I am trying to achieve. Didn't think it would be this complicated. So basically any image I use, Redis/Busybox, etc...those commands/configs need to live inside the image in order for this to work?

Comment: trying to get the logs but getting denied  /bin/bash: line 1: /root/checkpoint/eicar.sh: Permission denied

Comment: Why are you trying to run a container from another one? What's your use case? Running `nginx` from `redis` doesn't make ANY sense at all! Perhaps you're being driven to the wrong direction. Please let us know in details - this community is superb to bring you back on the right track. Running `kubectl logs <pod_name>` shouldn't give you any permission error, since you've already used it to deploy other pods. Of course you have to run it from your host machine, not through other container(s).

Comment: Maybe I was unclear of my use case. My intentions was to run a scheduled cronjob every 15 minutes using a script in my AWS cluster instead of manually invoking the script. I want to use kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx as the command to run in the script. Whether the script is successful or not is not important as we have an external portal with policies in place to block or enable the script from running. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @msrumon, not sure what you mean that hostPath doesnt work in AWS multi-node cluster. The above config is working for me and I can see the test-vol it created on the node and all connections between the cluster and nodes is confirmed.

Comment: Read [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#types-of-persistent-volumes) => `hostPath` point.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Makes sense. I will use your template to deploy and play around with different commands capable or running in the container.

Comment: See update as I just tried this on GCP

Comment: Don't update someone's answer. Update your question.

Comment: @msrumon, see my update

Comment: That's a different error. Please consider asking separate question for that.